# Create child records for parent created on same batch class

Tags: apex, batch, dml, childrecords

I have below code where I am creating parent object records in a batch class. I need to create the child records of the same on same batch class. Can someone please suggest a way out for this?

**Apex Code**

```
if(!MapOfAcctListItem.keyset().contains(key)){
  Account_List_vod__c Alst = new Account_List_vod__c();
                              Alst.Name = ListName;
                              Alst.Icon_Name_vod__c = '1';
                              Alst.OwnerId = Key;
                              InsertActList.add(Alst);  
}
```

Proper DML successfully inserts the records I checked works fine. But for child records can't as the batch already got executed.

Child records should be like this.

**Child records**

```
 Account_List_Item_vod__c Alstitem = new Account_List_Item_vod__c();
      Alstitem.Account_List_vod__c = ____;  // Get newly inserted records here
      Alstitem.Account_vod__c = actID;
      Alstitem.External_ID_vod__c = actID+'-'+key;
                              insAccListItem.add(Alstitem);
```

**DML for parent records**

```
 // Insert Acct Lists
      if(!InsertActList.isEmpty())
            {
                                try
                                {
                                    insert InsertActList;
                                    System.debug('InsertActListSize@'+InsertActList.size());
                                }
                            Catch(Exception Ex)
                            {
                                 system.debug(Ex);
                            }
            }




    // Insert Acct Lists : Completed
```

Comment: what do you mean by batch already got executed?  can you post the code where child records are created?

Comment: I mean when running the batch class i am not getting the master record's ID since DML is pending. So i couldn't create the child records.

Comment: can you post the code for inserting both master and child using batch class?

Comment: I couldn't code for the child having newly inserted Ids. I am updating my question on how I intend to.

Comment: @PreyaMohandoss  Please find my updated question.

Comment: What is your criteria for creating child records?You can create the records after inserting the parent records and taking the parent id in the same batch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52060/discussion-between-sfdc-learner-and-preya-mohandoss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
if(!InsertActList.isEmpty()){
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(InsertActList, false);

    for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
             Account_List_Item_vod__c Alstitem = new   Account_List_Item_vod__c();
             Alstitem.Account_List_vod__c = sr.getId();  
             Alstitem.Account_vod__c = actID;
             Alstitem.External_ID_vod__c = actID+'-'+key;
             insAccListItem.add(Alstitem);
        }
    }
    try {
        INSERT insAccListItem;
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the ownerId value of sr iteration?

Comment: You won't get `ownerId`. You need a separate query for that.